# capitalize  the last 2 characters in a string with freemarker?

Tags: java, string, freemarker

I have a freemarker variable, `${string}` which can be of any length. How would I capitalize just the last 2 characters?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [upper_case builtin](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_upper_case) and [sequence slicing](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_seqenceop_slice) on strings and write a FTL function like

```
<#function foo text>
  <#local len = text?length />
  <#if (len>2)>
    <#return text[0..len-3] + text[len-2..]?upper_case> 
  <#else>
    <#return text?upper_case>
  </#if>
</#function>
```

Then the FTL expression

```
${foo("foobar")}
```

produces the string `foobAR`.

Comment: awesome, thanks! That's what I was looking for. I've never used freemarker before, was trying to do it with weird substrings and all that mess. This is much cleaner. Thanks.